# How to pass json data as queryset object to django template?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have this json data in views.py

```
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "first_name": "Star",
        "last_initial": "W",
        "phone": "+918893972142",
        "email": "star@gmail.com",
        "date_created": "2020-10-12T17:17:17.629123Z",
        "orders": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "first_name": "Sam",
        "last_initial": "0",
        "phone": "+918766897214",
        "email": "sam@gmail.com",
        "date_created": "2020-10-12T17:13:33.435065Z",
        "orders": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "first_name": "Gaara",
        "last_initial": "W",
        "phone": "+918668972789",
        "email": "gaara@gmail.com",
        "date_created": "2020-10-12T17:08:44.906809Z",
        "orders": [
            {
                "order_id": "9",
                "customer_id": "3",
                "customer_name": "Gaara W",
                "product_id": "3",
                "product_name": "Jet",
                "date_created": "2020-10-12T17:18:18.823289Z",
                "status": "Delivered"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to pass this data as a context object to the template from views using render function. so I can display this data using {% for %} loop in my template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the data into the template.

```
return render(request, "app/template.html", {
    "data": data
})
```

Then you can use for loops to render the data you need.

Comment: it dosent work. when i try to access the inner keys using dotted notations, it simply prints the dotted string and not the value